# Weird Unload Behaviour - WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF application with a MainWindow. Set up an unloaded event in the code behind. Set the `MainWindow` as the startup uri. Unloaded is not triggered when the window is closed. Create a second window - `NotMainWindow` with a single button click.

In the button click event, call MainWindow. Close `MainWindow` and unloaded is triggered. **Why the difference in behaviour?** What I am trying to get at is, how do I get some kind of unloaded event **every** single time?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Unloaded="Main_Unloaded">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>

    private void Main_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.NotMainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="NotMainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Show Main" Height="25" Margin="10" Width="70" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
</Window>


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
        win.Show();
    }

<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="NotMainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: It is not called when it is closed. That is the issue. Of course it wouldn't be called on load! :P

Comment: @Blachshma - Corrected the question to remove the confusion.

Comment: So you're saying that you create the MainWindow and then immediately close it and the unloaded is not called?

Comment: Yeah. By immediately, I mean, pretty much anytime after the window is rendered on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments I understand the scenario you're talking about. This is a [known issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/e7a371dc-48af-4292-b1b4-2bd4459b4a00) that unloaded is not called when shutting down the application (e.g. last window is closed).

If you just want to know when the window is closed use the `Closing` event:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(MainWindow_Closing);
    InitializeComponent();
}


void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   // Closing logic here.
}
```

If you want to know when the last window is closed, e.g. your application is shutting down, you should use `ShutdownStarted`

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted += Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   //do what you want to do on app shutdown
}
```

Comment: Um. This looks like a reasonable solution. My problem is that actually, I need the Unload event in a control that I am building, not the window itself. The control could be hosted in any kind of window, but it cannot know anything about it's parent control. I need to do some cleanup in the unload of the control. :|

Comment: Accepted the answer for anyone who might need a solution to this problem. :)